# How can I get stats when using make to compile gcc?

Tags: gcc, makefile, statistics, gnu

I would like to get the stats about cpu usage, memory consumption, filesystem related stuff and the time spent compiling the various stages and components / sublibraries ( plus other important bits ), after a successful build done with `make` when building `gcc` .

It's possible to get stats out of `make` ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Another option is to use the make `SHELL` variable to replace the standard shell with a script or something that runs the program provided and computes the statistics you want.  You'll have to write that script yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool which can do everything.

For a very basic overview (time spent in the process), use `time make ...`.

If you need more details or exact figures, you need a profiler. For CPU usage, use `gprof`. For memory usage, you can use `valgrind`. For IO, you can use `ioprofile` or `iogrind`.